# Dynamic table in knockoutjs

Tags: html, knockout.js

I am using ajax call to get data its return data in json format like below:

```
{ "d" : [ 
  { "Goal" : "Some one client",
    "GoalID" : 1,
    "IsPublic" : true,
    "MemberName" : "user1"
  },                                         
  { "Goal" : " this is goal",
    "GoalID" : 1,
    "IsPublic" : false,
    "MemberName" : "user2"
  },           
  { "Goal" : "Get call",
    "GoalID" : 4,
    "IsPublic" : true,
    "MemberName" : "user2"
  }
] }
```

Now in my html page i want to create separate table for each user. Here is my table

```
//want username here then table for goal of that user 
<table>
  <thead>
     <tr class="headerRow">
      <th>member</th>
      <th>
         Goals
       </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
      <tbody data-bind="foreach: tasks">
      <tr">
       <td>
          <span data-bind="text: members" />
        </td>
        <td>
           <span data-bind="text: goal" />
         </td>
       </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

And "task" is the observable array containing all goal details.

This is my goal constuctor in javascript

```
 function Goal(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.goalID = data.GoalID;
    self.goal = data.Goal;
    self.isPublic = ko.observable(data.IsPublic);
    self.members = ko.observable(data.MemberName);
}
```

Comment: What issues do you have with this?

Comment: I want to create separate tables for each user. In my above code its create only one table for all members.

Comment: Could you create a fiddle?

Comment: I have created this one, but its not working  http://jsfiddle.net/TQXja/1/

Comment: Check this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/TQXja/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it is not the best solution but it will work. Add computed that returns all users:

```
self.users = ko.computed(function(){
    var list = ko.utils.arrayMap(self.tasks(), function(item){
        return item.members
    });
    return ko.utils.arrayGetDistinctValues(list);
});
```

And using `foreach` binding create a table for each user:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: users">
    <table>
      <thead>
         <tr>
          <th>membername</th>
          <th>
             Goals
           </th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
          <tbody data-bind="foreach: $parent.tasks">
          <tr data-bind="if: members == $parent">
           <td>
              <span data-bind="text: members" />
            </td>
            <td>
               <span data-bind="text: goals" />
             </td>
           </tr>
          </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here is working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TQXja/4/

Comment: But in my need, headers should remain only once and a blank row after same user

Comment: I have done this by applying nested foreach loop as in http://jsfiddle.net/TQXja/6/. But another thing i need is to get usernames in a row before the details instead of in column.

Comment: Just add another tr that will show user name before foreach with tasks. http://jsfiddle.net/TQXja/7/

Comment: Thanks for your help. Its filled my need.