# how to bind data to a table using knockoutjs in c# webforms

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-2.0

Iam getting data from backend, and now i want to bind that data to table in webforms

iam getting data from backend in this way

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod]    
    private string GetAll()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DEVENV1;Initial Catalog=KnockoutData;Integrated Security=True");       
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from sampledb", con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();            
    }
```

Now in Webforms by using jquery Ajax iam getting the data, something like this...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {
           $('#btnEdit').click(function () {
               var viewModel;
               $.ajax({
                   type: "GET",
                   url: "KnockoutJs.aspx/GetAll",
                   contentType: "application/json",
                   success: function (data) {
                       var result = JSON.parse(data);
                   }
               });
           });
<script>
```

now how to bind this data to below table, by using knockoutJs foreach

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Student Name</th>
<th>Roll No </th>
</tr>        
</table>
```

Comment: Take a look at this knockout [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html)

Answer (score 0):

Add a constructor in javascript class before viewModel and parse this value to that constructor.
check this link may help you:
[Dynamic table in knockoutjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13970521/dynamic-table-in-knockoutjs)